# Probabilistic/combinatoric proof of $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{tk+r}{k}\binom{t(n-k)+s}{n-k}\frac{r}{tk+r}=\binom{tn+r+s}{n}$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, alternative-proof

In [**this posting**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2814898/proof-of-a-combinatorial-abel-identity), OP asks a proof of the following identity

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{tk+r}{k}\binom{t(n-k)+s}{n-k} \frac{r}{tk+r} = \binom{tn+r+s}{n} \tag{1} $$

for non-negative integers $t, n, r, s$ with $t, n \geq 1$. I would like to reformulate this question in terms of probability. Here is my try:

**Setting.** Let $(\Omega, 2^{\Omega}, \mathbb{P})$ be the probability space where

- $\Omega = \{ \omega \subseteq [tn+r+s] : |\omega| = n\}$ is the family of all subsets of $[tn+r+s]$ with size $n$, and
- $\mathbb{P}$ is the law of uniform distribution on $\Omega$, i.e., $\mathbb{P}(\{\omega\}) = \frac{1}{|\Omega|}$ for each $\omega \in \Omega$.

Then define random variables $S_k$ and $T$ on $\Omega$ by

- $S_k(\omega) = \left|\omega\cap[tk+r]\right|$, for $k = 0, \cdots, n$,
- $T(\omega) := \min\{ k \geq 0 : S_k(\omega) = k \}$.

$\hspace{9em}$[image: Graph]

Since $k \mapsto S_k(\omega)$ is a non-decreasing function from $\{0,\cdots,n\}$ to itself, this map has a fixed point and the above definition makes sense. Then I am interested the following claim:

> **Claim.** We have $$ \mathbb{P}(T = k)
> = \frac{r}{tk+r} \frac{\binom{tk+r}{k}\binom{t(n-k)+s}{n-k}}{\binom{tn+r+s}{n}}. \tag{2} $$

Given this claim, the identity $\text{(1)}$ is simply $1 = \mathbb{P}(T < \infty) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \mathbb{P}(T = k) $. I checked this claim for various values of $t, n, r, s$ but was unable to establish a proof.

So, **here is a question:** Although there is a proof using complex analysis in the [original posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2814898/proof-of-a-combinatorial-abel-identity), I would be happy to know whether a probabilistic or combinatorial proof of $\text{(1)}$ or $\text{(2)}$ is available, not necessarily based on the setting above.

It might be helpful to note that $\text{(2)}$ is equivalent to proving the following problem:

> For each $k$, the number of subsets $A$ of $[tk+r]$ satisfying $|A| = k$ and $|A\cap[tj+r]| > j$ for all $j<k$ is given by $\frac{r}{tk+r}\binom{tk+r}{k}$.

This sounds like a generalization of Catalan numbers, although I have no good idea for this.

Comment: Do you need $r>0$ in (1)?

Comment: @InterstellarProbe, Thank you for pointing out an issue. It is safe to assume $r > 0$, while we may interpret $\frac{r}{tk+r}=\delta_{k,0}$ for $r=0$ to make $\text{(1)}$ sense.

Comment: Isn't the starting identity a consequence of the [Rothe-Hagen identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rothe%E2%80%93Hagen_identity)? I recall that Micheal Spivey wrote an interesting post about it in his blog. Here it is: https://mikespivey.wordpress.com/2015/09/04/combinatorial-proofs-of-two-hagen-rothe-identities-in-concrete-mathematics/

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, I was never aware of that identity. So glad to know the name and reference. Thank you! If you are willing to migrate your comment to an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The starting identity a consequence of the [Rothe-Hagen identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rothe%E2%80%93Hagen_identity). Micheal Spivey [wrote an interesting post](https://mikespivey.wordpress.com/2015/09/04/combinatorial-proofs-of-two-hagen-rothe-identities-in-concrete-mathematics/) about it in his blog and combinatorial proofs from Wenchang Chu are freely available [here](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v17i1n24/pdf).